# What to do after using PyInstaller for Mac OS

Tags: pyinstaller

This is just for educational purposes because I've always been curious about how apps are made.

I installed PyInstaller and ran my pyinstall command to turn my python scripts into a stand alone application. I got the output from PyInstaller. Now what do I do to package this app for Macs?

Comment: What exactly you are asking about? pyinstaller has created you an executable. Just run it.

Comment: Yeah. There is a folder of my program in /dist right? I don't know what to do after that.